# Screencast or video for Database programs in JAVA

Tags: java, sql-server

Can someone point me towards a good video tutorial that teaches how to connect to a database (preferrably SQL Server) USING JAVA TO insert data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you need a video tutorial for that? There are plenty of "normal" (hey just text) tutorial out there on the web. What is the benefit of a video tutorial?

[HOW TO: Get Started with Microsoft JDBC](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313100/EN-US/)

[JDBC 101: Connect to a SQL database with JDBC](http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010024/)

And many more. Google for "sqlserver" and "jdbc" and "connect" and you are done.